# Bignum Vector Usage in C++

Tags: c++, vector, bignum

What do I do to make a vector contain GMP bignum double values in C++. My code only works up until over a million. Here's what I have in my code now:

```
vector<double> Primes;
```

What should it be?
I have checked and I can't find anything about this. Is the use normal.

Comment: Can't you just use `vector<GMP> Primes`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a GMP big double, that's a standard built-in C++ double.

What about this?

```
std::vector<mpf_class> Primes;
```

But since you (seemingly) are putting primes in a vector I suspect you want integers, not floating point numbers. Then this is appropriate:

```
std::vector<mpz_class> Primes;
```

Comment: I need to perform arithmetic on the values that has accuracy to at least 3 decimal points.

Comment: How big are your values, and what kind of arithmic?

Comment: Up to 1,000,000,000. I need to divide numbers by the values in Primes and I need to know what the decimal is after it. Actually, in retrospect, it appears that ints would actually be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation a GMP number is initialized using

```
mpz_t q;
```

Making the vector initialization

```
std::vector<mpz_t> primes
```

Also why are your Primes double permission?